# Why ParNew gc took too much time in the second time?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My application stoped too long in ParNew GC, gc log:
`2021-01-27T07:12:36.921+0800: 138428.923: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-01-27T07:12:38.569+0800: 138430.572: [ParNew:(Age info) 1259050K->686K(1415616K), 0.0317991 secs] 1548016K->289664K(2988480K), 1.6805050 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=1.68 secs]`

The first time `0.0317991 secs` is good，but the second time `1.6805050 secs` took too much time, what's GC do in here?

I have checked host machine, every metrics are fine, no memory swap.

Java Opts is here:
`-server -Xmx3072M -Xms3072M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=3 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=7 -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:-UseCounterDecay -Xloggc:/dev/shm/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseCountedLoopSafepoints -XX:-UseBiasedLocking`

GC log is here:

```
2021-01-27T07:12:10.828+0800: 138402.830: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-01-27T07:12:10.828+0800: 138402.830: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 80510976 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 7)
    - age   1:     259304 bytes,     259304 total
    - age   2:      46280 bytes,     305584 total
    - age   3:      63160 bytes,     368744 total
    - age   4:       3736 bytes,     372480 total
    - age   5:      59696 bytes,     432176 total
    - age   6:      25152 bytes,     457328 total
    - age   7:      12304 bytes,     469632 total
    : 1258981K->682K(1415616K), 0.0245784 secs] 1547917K->289648K(2988480K), 0.0250207 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
    2021-01-27T07:12:36.921+0800: 138428.923: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-01-27T07:12:38.569+0800: 138430.572: [ParNew
    Desired survivor size 80510976 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 7)
    - age   1:     274576 bytes,     274576 total
    - age   2:      45920 bytes,     320496 total
    - age   3:       4600 bytes,     325096 total
    - age   4:      39272 bytes,     364368 total
    - age   5:       3528 bytes,     367896 total
    - age   6:      57952 bytes,     425848 total
    - age   7:      24960 bytes,     450808 total
    : 1259050K->686K(1415616K), 0.0317991 secs] 1548016K->289664K(2988480K), 1.6805050 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=1.68 secs] 
    2021-01-27T07:13:00.162+0800: 138452.165: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2021-01-27T07:13:00.163+0800: 138452.165: [ParNew
    Desired survivor size 80510976 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 7)
    - age   1:    1950848 bytes,    1950848 total
    - age   2:     119144 bytes,    2069992 total
    - age   3:       5160 bytes,    2075152 total
    - age   4:       4000 bytes,    2079152 total
    - age   5:      38936 bytes,    2118088 total
    - age   6:       2648 bytes,    2120736 total
    - age   7:      56280 bytes,    2177016 total
    : 1259054K->2291K(1415616K), 0.0262994 secs] 1548032K->291293K(2988480K), 0.0267862 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are worried about the `1.68 secs` in  `[Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=1.68 secs]`.

That is the elapsed time.  The user and system CPU time for the collection are ... tiny.  It is hard to see how the GC itself would cause a particular collection to take a long (wall clock) time without consuming CPU time.

So my tentative diagnosis is that this most likely caused by something other that the JVM.  Possibilities include:

- Some other higher priority processes running on your computer were using most of the CPU resources.
- Your system was suffering from memory thrashing ... caused by the behavior of some other process.
- The OS experienced some kind of problem that caused everything to lock up for a second or so.
- You are running in a virtual server, and your virtual server was resource starved for some reason.  (Various things could cause that.)

If this was a once-off, it could be hard to track down.  If it is a regular occurrence, look for correlations with other system (or hypervisor) level performance measures.  Also, see if there is some correlation with the time of day; e.g. when backups are being run.